# Secure redirecting to the desired page after loging in

Tags: php, redirect

Note: this question is about security of redirecting not the redirecting itself.

Scenario: User wants to visit some page - but he is not logged in - so I store the desired page in the GET parameter - and after loging in successfully user gets redirected to the desired page.

However I surely dont trust the GET parameter - how to solve this?

I figured out 2 options:

1) Store it in session variable - that should provide a reliable source because my domain is the only subject that can work with its session variables - good idea or not?

2) Check if the desired url starts with "`/`" which would mean that the url is based on root => trusted ,
 - is that reliable? can I trust the 
`if( $_GET['redirect'][0] == "/" ) header('Location: '.$_GET['redirect']);` ?

Comment: Why don't you trust the GET parameter? You can filter it easily and also, if the link has to redirect elsewhere, a 404 will be thrown.

Comment: Well what if someone do `mydomain.com?next=http://virusintoyourpc.bad` ??

Comment: Just use GET, as long as you are not changing any data or passing sensitive information you will be fine. If you are worried about someone trying to redirect to another site just use a filter.

Comment: Why not store the current URL in a SESSION variable instead and then redirect to that after login?

Comment: @stckrboy that was the 1st option I've suggested... So you think its better?